# variable defined in componenetDidMount() is not available

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set values for the couple of variables in **componentDidMount()**. However these global variables are appearing as undefined in my other functions.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.authorInfo = document.getElementById("authorInfo");
    this.bottomDistance = this.authorInfo.offsetTop;
    console.log(this.authorInfo);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollListener, false);
  }
scrollListener() {
      console.log(this.bottomDistance);
      if (window.pageYOffset >= this.bottomDistance) {
        this.authorInfo.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        this.authorInfo.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }

render() {
  return(
   .....
   <div id="authorInfo">
              <Heading articleName="About The Author" titleFont="large"/>
              <div className={style.profileInfo}>
                <div style={{marginRight: '30px'}}>
                  <Image src="../../resources/images/profile.jpg" mode="fill" style={{height:'90px', width:'90px',borderRadius: '50%', display: 'inline-block'}} />
                </div>
                <span className={style.infoPanelText}>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
  )
}
```

Both **authorInfo** and **bottomDistance** are appearing as undefined in my scrollListeners. 
PS: I have tried **ref** attribute also to assign the value of global variables.

Comment: But, he did share an MCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.bind()` to tell JavaScript what "context" to use:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.authorInfo = document.getElementById("authorInfo");
  this.bottomDistance = this.authorInfo.offsetTop;
  console.log(this.authorInfo);
  // Notice .bind here -->                                vvvv
  document.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollListener.bind(this), false);
}
scrollListener() {
  console.log(this.bottomDistance);
  if (window.pageYOffset >= this.bottomDistance) {
    this.authorInfo.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    this.authorInfo.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

When you pass the `scrollListener` function without binding or calling it, the function loses its context, so `this` inside the unbound version refers to the `window`.

More info on `.bind()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: This article talks about different ways to ensure that the `this` context doesn't change: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` context by using arrow function in method declaration
`scrollListener = () => { /* ... */ }` without manually binding it in constructor.